# Javascript to JQuery - Rendering the User Input in a Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rendering, appendchild

I have a javascript function meant to append the contents of a text field to a list, in order to make it render as soon as the user clicks a button next to the text field. The button and text field show up fine, but I've been told that I need to convert my function to JQuery, whose syntax I'm far less familiar with than javascript. This is the function:

```
document.getElementById("append").onclick = function()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("new-text").value;

    var li = "<li>" + text + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

`list` is the list I want to append the text field contents to, and `new-text` is the id for the text field content.

Comment: This may be water under the bridge, but why is someone asking you to "convert JavaScript to jQuery"?  Do they even realize that jQuery is still Just JavaScript (TM)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#append').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#new-text').val();
    var li = '<li>' + text + '</li>';
    $('#list').append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var text = $('#text').val();
    var li;
    li = $('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    $("#ul").append(li);
})
```

You can have it like this. I named the button with the id `button` on the event that button is clicked it will get the value of textbox with the id `text` and then append it to the `ul` with the id `ul`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vcd7whoz/)

Or if you want to have the event called from a function you can have it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vcd7whoz/1/)

```
$('#button').click(function () {
   buttonclick();
})

function buttonclick(){
    var text = $('#text').val();
    var li;
    li = $('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    $("#ul").append(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why fix what ain't broke? jQuery is mostly useful as a time saver so you don't have to write out the longer vanilla javascript syntax, but I can't imagine a situation in which it should be required. Nevertheless:

```
$("#append").click(function()
{
    var text = $("#new-text").val();
    var li = $("<li>"+text+"</li>");
    $("#list").append(li);
});
```